# JQuery .ajax not sending request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

I am not able to send POST/Get requests using jquery. I have a python Flask server set up. Curl requests work perfectly. I could see requests hitting the server but these ajax requests not hitting the server. Below is the code i've been working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

         $("#b1").click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: 'http://np.mystiq.xyz/paste',
                 complete: function(response) {
                     $('#output').html(response.responseText);
                 },
                 error: function() {
                     $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
                 },
             });
         });
     });

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <button id="b1">test success </button>
  <div id="output"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

but this fiddle seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/zc59uLnc/ So issue is with JQuery. Not sure what exactly is the issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it stuck at cross domain? What if you are requesting it from the same domain?
If it is cross domain, set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`
See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

Change error to:

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!  Check the console for details.');
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
}
```

And it should point you to the solution.

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/zc59uLnc/ seems to work but my html which i posted doesn't work :(

Comment: console shows code of jquery. looks like it did not throw error. https://jsbin.com/jezeqavime/edit?html,console,output

Comment: There is no error.  Your URL is returning responseText: ""

Comment: responseText is supposed to be {"status":"OK"} and i dont see requests hitting my server :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your view accepts POST HTTP method? did you test with POST or GET when you were using curl?

The following code works for me:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    return jsonify({'test': 'test message'})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

In **templates/index.html**, I just pasted your template and changed your url to:

```
url: 'http://my_vm_ip:5000/hello'
```

instead of:

```
url: 'http://np.mystiq.xyz/paste'
```

If you have some cross domain issue, add the following code to your app.py file:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    return response
```

Comment: Yes it accepts POST and curl -X POST 'np.mystiq.xyz/paste' works fine but via ajax it fails

Comment: Did you try the code snippet in my answer? and what is the error that you are getting when you load your page? (you can check your chrome console to see the generated errors)

Comment: there are no error.. i did try the snippet.. but did not help .. i'm not sure if u checked my edited post.. http://jsfiddle.net/zc59uLnc/  works but not in my code..

Comment: Are you sure you checked that you are not getting any error in your chrome console? please use F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (on PC) and make sure that nothing is displayed on your console tab. Also, click on Network tab and see if a request is sent when you click on "test success" button. For me I get the correct result when I click on that button.